# How do I limit the number of selected option tags within a select tag in jQuery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to limit the number of selected option tags in jQuery to 100.  What am I doing wrong?  The select tag looks like this:

```
<select name="order">
<option value="1" selected>Order Name</option> ...
```

after a user selects one or more option tags...  Still not sure how to get the event handler to work.

```
var countSelectedOptionTags
$("select[name='order']").change(function() {
  $("select[name='order']").children('attr="selected"').each(function() {
     countSelectedOptionTags++;
  });
  if countSelectedOptionTags > 100 
  {
     alert("You can not select more than 100 option tag.");
     return;

  }   //I need the option tags that have the selected attribute
```

Comment: Does it work in jquery-1.3.2.min.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("select[name='order'] option:selected")
```

will give you all the options that are selected.

```
$("select[name='order'] option:selected:gt(99)");
```

will give options that are selected and have an index greater than 100

```
var countSelectedOptionTags = 0;
$("select[name='order']").change(function() {
    var selectedOptions = $("select[name='order'] option:selected");
  countSelectedOptionTags = selectedOptions.length;
  if countSelectedOptionTags > 100 
  {
     alert("You can not select more than 100 option tag.");
     return;
  }
    .
    .
    .
});
```

Comment: Yeah that works, but I need to remove all but 100 of the last attributes now. Sheesh

Comment: @Marc: Updated the post to get selected options greater than 100. Pls check.

Comment: @Marc: Also, from my perspective a select element with more than 100 elements is not a user friendly component.